# Eclipse opens old versions of my project

Tags: eclipse, refresh, version, project

When opening Eclipse the project version is not the current one(it automatically opens the very beginning version of the project, not the current files on my drive). 
I tried modifying the refresh settings in Preferences->Workspace, no luck. Also, when I right click->Refresh the project nothing happens.
I am using the last version of Eclipse Luna and the PyDev perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look that its clearly the Workspace you would to use.
Do you have different Workspaces?

Comment: I only have one Workspace.

Comment: Do you have a different Version of Eclipse on your System?

Comment: Apparently creating a new workspace in a different location worked.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried go *File* then *Switch Workspace* e selected the right one? (even if ther is only one)

Some time it happend to me, maybe when i have eclipse opened and i click again on the eclipse startup app it ask me "load new workspace..." and it messup all

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the location of the project.

1. Right-click on the project in Package Explorer and select "Properties"
2. Select "Resources" on right side and check the location.

If the location is wrong, try to import the right one using method as follows:

1. Right-click in Package Explorer and select "Import"
2. Select General->Existing Projects into Workspace and import the project.

Comment: The location is the right one, it even shows the last modified time correctly